# Output key and value in one array row

Tags: php, arrays

I want to set two fields in one row when outputting my array result like:

```
{
  "key" : "value",
...
}
```

in my part of code:

```
$letter = $this->getMyRepository()->findAll();

    $result = array();

    foreach($letter as $key => $value){
        $id = $value->getId();
        if(!isset($result[$id])) $result[$id] = array();
        $result[$id][] = $value->getKey() . ' ' . $value->getValue();

        print_r($value);die;
    }
```

but it returns just Key fields.

Comment: How is your `$value` object is look like? can you add code example?

Comment: Key and Value are both strings and are the same, just in another language. @dWinder

Comment: `$result[$myResult][] = $value->Key . ' ' . $value->value();`. try this or show us `var_dump($value);` data

Comment: This can't work as its object in matter. It's in Symfony project.  When dumping value it's  [id:protected] => 9457
    [id:Base\Entity] => View all
    [key:Base\Entity:private] => en @AlivetoDie
    [value:Base\Entity:private] => english

Comment: If the fields are "private" I don't think you can do `$value->getValue()`

Comment: They are. It's returnig  all $value->getKey() results but It wont input them together like  { This is key : This Is vaule } @dWinder

Comment: What if you do a json_encode on your array and output the json encoded string?

Comment: I already done that in my code.I have field Key and field Value that I want to output in a same row like I showed below. I tried with || and &&. It returns just Key value @MER

Comment: You need to post way more code than this. You're using custom functions to pull keys and values, how are we supposed to know if that code is even correct?

Comment: but not with anything that would tell us what's happening inside getKey and getValue